# Cannot load jupyter-notebook from terminal in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, jupyter-notebook

After installing the latest version of Anaconda, and following post-installation steps, I am not able to load jupyter notebook on my system, Ubuntu 14.04.

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/jupyter-notebook", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(notebook.notebookapp.main())
  File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core    /application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 588, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1023, in initialize
self.init_webapp()
  File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 882, in init_webapp
xheaders=self.trust_xheaders)
  File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/util.py", line 221, in __new__
instance.initialize(*args, **init_kwargs)
  File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 155, in initialize
read_chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/home/carlos/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 112, in __init__
self.ssl_options['certfile'])
ValueError: certfile "jupnb.pem" does not exist
```

The certfile actually exists, in the directory ~/.jupyter/

I haven't been lucky googling the solution. Any comments?

Thanks!
Carlos

Comment: How have you configured the certificate file? If you've just given it a file name, try specifying a full path.

Comment: @ThomasK I have not configured the certificate file :-/ I have been following the instructions I've found like a zombie, hoping for everything to work out-of-the-box instantly ... dear me! :-) ... 
I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: What instructions are you following? By default, it doesn't use a certificate file at all.

Comment: The ones at https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any post-installation instructions? :-/ What created or told you to create the certificate file?

Comment: The first news I had about the certificate file is with the error message I get when running "jupyter notebook" command.
I could try uninstalling all python related software, and re-install again. This time, only installing Anaconda which comes with all the scientific features I need too.

Comment: It shouldn't be doing anything with a certificate file by default. Maybe Anaconda is setting something else up on install.

Comment: That could be it ... Maybe they are still transitioning from iPython to Jupyter ...

Answer (score 0):

edit `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` and check the correct paths,

e.g. for `~/.jupyter/jupnb.key` and `~/.jupyter/jupnb.pem`:

```
import os
c.NotebookApp.keyfile = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.jupyter/jupnb.key'
c.NotebookApp.certfile = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.jupyter/jupnb.pem'
```